# How to import data from SQL Azure to O365 outlook Calendar

Tags: outlook, azure-sql-database, office365

Any advice is appreciated.

I am trying to import a list of user data from Azure SQL to Outlook Calendar.

I know that I can do it in PowerShell. But, looking if there is other options other than powershell.

Many Thanks,
serenity

Comment: What is "user data"? List of contacts? Messages? Or something else?

Comment: individual user timetable to be push into outlook calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 :**

You could use Logic App / Power Automate (Formerly called Microsoft Flow)

The below connector will get the row from the SQL Server :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#get-rows-v2-action-aggregation-transformation-parameter-detail

[image]

You could iterate through each row using the for each (in logic app) or Apply to each ( in power automate)

[image]

Create a calendar event accordingly using the [Create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#create-event-(v4)) connector

[image]

**Option 2 :**

If you would like to provide an UI where in User will have to go ahead trigger for themselves - you could use [MS Powerapps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) - which also has the related connectors and the actions are done under the user

**Option 3 :**

You could expose your server data over Rest API and consume the same in your application.
For instance, you could use [Skyvia Connect](https://skyvia.com/connect/sql-azure-odata) for the same. In the same application you could make use of the Outlook APIs to [create/manager the calendar events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Is this suggestion for a single user? I am looking to push the data for all users in the company.          I have user x, y, z and I need to access their outlook to create events on their behalf

Comment: But getting other mailbox's permission would be against privacy if I m not wrong - please correct me if i m wrong - but if you are looking to block other specific people's calendar - you could populate the `required attendees` (updated the screen shot in my answer)

Comment: This will eventually block the calendar and populate the event in the respective user's calendar

Comment: The idea would be to have an automation account and block the calendars of people using the above method - in this way you don't need explicit permission / impersonation of the users - you do the same for all the users.

Comment: pls do let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work